# Pass column name in data.table using variable

Tags: r, data.table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variably selecting/assigning to fields in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/variably-selecting-assigning-to-fields-in-a-data-table)

In following example, I am creating a data table having column name ‘x’ and ‘v’

```
library('data.table')
DT <- data.table(x = c("b","b","b","a","a"), v = rnorm(5))
```

I can access values of column ‘x’ by :

```
DT[ , x]
# [1] "b" "b" "b" "a" "a"
```

But if I want to access by passing through a variable, it doesn’t work

```
temp <- "x"
DT[ , temp]
# [1] "x"
```

There would be multiple columns and I will have to select values for only couple of them. These column names I will be provide by passing through a R module.

Never mind, I got it, it should be:

```
DT[ , get(temp)]
```

Comment: use `get` function

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the `quote()` and `eval()` functions to pass a variable to `j`. You don't need double-quotes on the column names when you do it this way, because the `quote()`-ed string will be evaluated inside the `DT[]`

```
temp <- quote(x)
DT[ , eval(temp)]
# [1] "b" "b" "b" "a" "a"
```

With a single column name, the result is a vector. If you want a data.table result, or several columns, use list form

```
temp <- quote(list(x, v))
DT[ , eval(temp)]
#   x           v
# 1: b  1.52566586
# 2: b  0.66057253
# 3: b -1.29654641
# 4: a -1.71998260
# 5: a  0.03159933
```

Comment: For me with R 3.2.0 this does not work. I have to use get(temp) as pointed out by the thread starter.

Comment: I already have a gazillion column names in a character vector all there with double quotes around them. How do I get rid of the quotes?

Comment: And what happens if you already have about 10 columns names in a list statement but you want to add the other gazillion column names. So for the example above it would be something such as `DT[,list(favoritecolumn1, favoritecolumn2, favoritecolumn3, temp)`

Comment: @exocom ... I had the same issue and used the folllowing answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/select-assign-to-data-table-variables-which-names-are-stored-in-a-character-ve

Comment: This works for me: `DT[, colnames, with=FALSE][[colnum]]`

Comment: `get()` function works in both `i` and `j` (R version 3.6.3, data.table version 1.12.8), which is an added benefit.