# Using dynamic column names in `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table

I want to calculate mean of each of several columns in a data.table, grouped by another column. My question is similar to two other questions on SO ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/variably-selecting-assigning-to-fields-in-a-data-table) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603890/pass-column-name-in-data-table-using-variable-in-r)) but I couldn't apply those on my problem.

Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
dtb <- fread(input = "condition,var1,var2,var3
      one,100,1000,10000
      one,101,1001,10001
      one,102,1002,10002
      two,103,1003,10003
      two,104,1004,10004
      two,105,1005,10005
      three,106,1006,10006
      three,107,1007,10007
      three,108,1008,10008
      four,109,1009,10009
      four,110,1010,10010")

dtb
#    condition var1 var2  var3
# 1:       one  100 1000 10000
# 2:       one  101 1001 10001
# 3:       one  102 1002 10002
# 4:       two  103 1003 10003
# 5:       two  104 1004 10004
# 6:       two  105 1005 10005
# 7:     three  106 1006 10006
# 8:     three  107 1007 10007
# 9:     three  108 1008 10008
# 10:     four  109 1009 10009
# 11:     four  110 1010 10010
```

The calculation of each single mean is easy; e.g. for "var1": `dtb[ , mean(var1), by = condition]`. But I this quickly becomes cumbersome if there are many variables and you need to write all of them. Thus, `dtb[, list(mean(var1), mean(var2), mean(var3)), by = condition]` is undesirable. I need the column names to be dynamic and I wish to end up with something like this:

```
   condition  var1   var2    var3
1:       one 101.0 1001.0 10001.0
2:       two 104.0 1004.0 10004.0
3:     three 107.0 1007.0 10007.0
4:      four 109.5 1009.5 10009.5
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

you should use `.SDcols` (especially if you've too many columns and you require a particular operation to be performed only on a subset of the columns (apart from the grouping variable columns).

```
dtb[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=condition, .SDcols=2:4]

#    condition  var1   var2    var3
# 1:       one 101.0 1001.0 10001.0
# 2:       two 104.0 1004.0 10004.0
# 3:     three 107.0 1007.0 10007.0
# 4:      four 109.5 1009.5 10009.5
```

You could also get all the column names you'd want to take mean of first in a variable and then pass it to `.SDcols` like this:

```
keys <- setdiff(names(dtb), "condition")
# keys = var1, var2, var3
dtb[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=condition, .SDcols=keys]
```

**Edit:** As Matthew Dowle rightly pointed out, since you require mean to be computed on every other column after grouping by `condition`, you could just do:

```
dtb[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=condition]
```

**David's edit:** (which got rejected): Read more about `.SD` from [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508482/what-does-sd-stand-for-in-data-table-in-r). I find this is relevant here. Thanks @David.

**Edit 2:** Suppose you have a `data.table` with 1000 rows and 301 columns (one column for grouping and 300 numeric columns):

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(45)
dt <- data.table(grp = sample(letters[1:15], 1000, replace=T))
m  <- matrix(rnorm(300*1000), ncol=300)
dt <- cbind(dt, m)
setkey(dt, "grp")
```

and you wanted to find the mean of the columns, say, 251:300 alone,

- you can compute the mean of all the columns and then subset these columns (which is not very efficient as you'll compute on the whole data).

  ```
  dt.out <- dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=grp]
  dim(dt.out) # 15 * 301, not efficient.
  ```
- you can filter the `data.table` first to just these columns and then compute the mean (which is again not necessarily the best solution as you have to create an extra subset'd data.table every time you want operations on certain columns.

  ```
  dt.sub <- dt[, c(1, 251:300)]
  setkey(dt.sub, "grp")
  dt.out <- dt.sub[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=grp]
  ```
- you can specify each of the columns one by one as you'd normally do (but this is desirable for smaller data.tables)

  ```
  # if you just need one or few columns
  dt.out <- dt[, list(m.v251 = mean(V251)), by = grp]
  ```

So what's the best solution? The answer is **.SDcols**.

> As the documentation states, for a *data.table x*, **.SDcols** specifies the columns that are included in **.SD**.

This basically implicitly filters the columns that will be passed to .SD instead of creating a subset (as we did before), only it is VERY efficient and FAST!

How can we do this?

- By specifiying either the column numbers:

  ```
  dt.out <- dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=grp, .SDcols = 251:300]
  dim(dt.out) # 15 * 51 (what we expect)
  ```
- Or alternatively by specifying the column id:

  ```
  ids <- paste0("V", 251:300) # get column ids
  dt.out <- dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=grp, .SDcols = ids]
  dim(dt.out) # 15 * 51 (what we expect)
  ```

It accepts both column names and numbers as arguments. In both these cases, .SD will be provided only with these columns we've specified.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Arun can you please explain the .SDcols syntax, I can't find any relevant documentaiton

Comment: @DavidD, hope the `edit 2` helps. To others, please feel free to edit the edits if something is not just about right or could be improved for better understanding.

Comment: +1 Amazing answer. Wasn't aware of the `.SDcols` option myself, this is definitely helpful!

Comment: @Arun it wasn't rejected, I just don't have enought reputation to edit others' answers, thus my edits require moderation by either answer author or a community member with enough reputation score.

Comment: @DavidD, yes, I approved the edit to see the it was not approved by others. You require a few votes and it dint pass through.

Comment: How about doing the same thing but without grouping? Suppose you have several columns which are dates stored in strings, and you want to apply as.Date to them, obviously reassigning the result to the same column. You don't need to group here, so when I try lapply(.SD,as.Date) it complains about .SD not existing. I could use any column that is unique as a key and then group, but that sound like a kludge and maybe inefficient

Comment: @Juancentro, it's hard to grasp exactly what's the issue. Maybe it's better to post it as a question.. no?

Comment: @Arun is it possible to do perform a different function (e.g. `sum()`) on another column at the same time as using `.SDcols` and lapply to subset and perform a calculation?