# Accessing columns in data.table using a character vector of column names

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have an R data.table:

```
 DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
```

and I have a character vector of column names that I would like to extract, or more generally operate on:

```
cols = c("x","y")
```

For example, how can I use cols to generate the equivalent of

```
 DT[,lapply(.SD[,list(x,y)], min) ]
```

Is there a way to specify the list(x,y) using the cols vector?

Comment: Similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937165/using-dynamic-column-names-in-data-table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `data.table` syntax `..` which "looks up one level" (as in the Unix terminal) for the variable:

```
> all.equal(DT[,list(x,y)], DT[, ..cols])
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(DT[,.SD[,list(x,y)][min(v)]], DT[,.SD[ ,min(v)], .SDcols = cols])
[1] TRUE
```

More details under FAQ 1.6 I believe: http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf

Comment: Thanks!  I changed my question a bit while you were answering it, but the solution still seems good.

Comment: Using with=FALSE inside an .SD seems like a useful idiom.  If that's a recommended approach for data.table, I wonder if it should be in the data.table or examples or FAQ? @MatthewDowle

Comment: @DavidR Maybe '.SDcols' ?  See ?data.table and search this tag for "SDcols".

Comment: @DavidR No problem. A particularly good answer on .SDcols from a few days ago not to miss : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14937323/403310