# log transform on columns generates warnings in r

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, transformation

I have some columns in a data frame which I need to log-transform.

I'm using the following code to do so:

```
cols = c("LotArea", "MasVnrArea", "LotFrontage", "BsmtFinSF2", "LowQualFinSF", 
         "BsmtHalfBath", "KitchenAbvGr", "OpenPorchSF",
         "EnclosedPorch", "MiscVal", "PoolArea", "3SsnPorch", "ScreenPorch")
train[, which(names(train) %in% cols)] <- log(train[, which(names(train) %in% cols)] + 1, 2)
```

And I'm getting a lot of these warnings:

```
Supplied 13 items to be assigned to 1455 items of column 'LotFrontage' (recycled leaving remainder of 12 items)
```

And also:

```
Coerced 'double' RHS to 'integer' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision.
Either change the target column to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 1455 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column),
or coerce RHS to 'integer' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed.
Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please
```

I Have the same warning(s) for each of the columns specified, all of them are `int` columns

Am I Doing something wrong?

To help reproduce, Here's the output of `dput(head(train))` :

```
structure(list(Id = 1:6, MSSubClass = c(60L, 20L, 60L, 70L, 60L, 
50L), MSZoning = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("C (all)", 
"FV", "RH", "RL", "RM"), class = "factor"), LotFrontage = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), LotArea = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Street = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Alley = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), LotShape = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("IR1", "IR2", "IR3", "Reg"), class = "factor"), 
    LandContour = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Bnk", 
    "HLS", "Low", "Lvl"), class = "factor"), Utilities = c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), LotConfig = structure(c(5L, 3L, 5L, 
    1L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Corner", "CulDSac", "FR2", "FR3", 
    "Inside"), class = "factor"), LandSlope = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), Neighborhood = structure(c(6L, 25L, 6L, 7L, 14L, 
    12L), .Label = c("Blmngtn", "Blueste", "BrDale", "BrkSide", 
    "ClearCr", "CollgCr", "Crawfor", "Edwards", "Gilbert", "IDOTRR", 
    "MeadowV", "Mitchel", "NAmes", "NoRidge", "NPkVill", "NridgHt", 
    "NWAmes", "OldTown", "Sawyer", "SawyerW", "Somerst", "StoneBr", 
    "SWISU", "Timber", "Veenker"), class = "factor"), Condition1 = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Artery", "Feedr", "Norm", 
    "PosA", "PosN", "RRAe", "RRAn", "RRNe", "RRNn"), class = "factor"), 
    Condition2 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Artery", 
    "Feedr", "Norm", "PosA", "PosN", "RRAe", "RRAn", "RRNn"), class = "factor"), 
    BldgType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1Fam", 
    "2fmCon", "Duplex", "Twnhs", "TwnhsE"), class = "factor"), 
    HouseStyle = structure(c(6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("1.5Fin", 
    "1.5Unf", "1Story", "2.5Fin", "2.5Unf", "2Story", "SFoyer", 
    "SLvl"), class = "factor"), OverallQual = c(7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
    8L, 5L), OverallCond = c(5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), YearBuilt = c(2003L, 
    1976L, 2001L, 1915L, 2000L, 1993L), YearRemodAdd = c(2003L, 
    1976L, 2002L, 1970L, 2000L, 1995L), RoofStyle = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Flat", "Gable", "Gambrel", 
    "Hip", "Mansard", "Shed"), class = "factor"), RoofMatl = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ClyTile", "CompShg", "Membran", 
    "Metal", "Roll", "Tar&Grv", "WdShake", "WdShngl"), class = "factor"), 
    Exterior1st = structure(c(13L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("AsbShng", 
    "AsphShn", "BrkComm", "BrkFace", "CBlock", "CemntBd", "HdBoard", 
    "ImStucc", "MetalSd", "Plywood", "Stone", "Stucco", "VinylSd", 
    "Wd Sdng", "WdShing"), class = "factor"), Exterior2nd = structure(c(14L, 
    9L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 14L), .Label = c("AsbShng", "AsphShn", 
    "Brk Cmn", "BrkFace", "CBlock", "CmentBd", "HdBoard", "ImStucc", 
    "MetalSd", "Other", "Plywood", "Stone", "Stucco", "VinylSd", 
    "Wd Sdng", "Wd Shng"), class = "factor"), MasVnrType = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "BrkCmn", "BrkFace", 
    "Stone"), class = "factor"), MasVnrArea = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), ExterQual = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), ExterCond = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Foundation = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("BrkTil", "CBlock", "PConc", "Slab", 
    "Stone", "Wood"), class = "factor"), BsmtQual = c(4L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 4L), BsmtCond = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), BsmtExposure = c(1L, 
    4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), BsmtFinType1 = c(6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
    6L), BsmtFinSF1 = c(706L, 978L, 486L, 216L, 655L, 732L), 
    BsmtFinType2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BsmtFinSF2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BsmtUnfSF = c(150L, 284L, 434L, 540L, 
    490L, 64L), TotalBsmtSF = c(856L, 1262L, 920L, 756L, 1145L, 
    796L), Heating = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Floor", 
    "GasA", "GasW", "Grav", "OthW", "Wall"), class = "factor"), 
    HeatingQC = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L), CentralAir = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Electrical = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
    ), `1stFlrSF` = c(856L, 1262L, 920L, 961L, 1145L, 796L), 
    `2ndFlrSF` = c(854L, 0L, 866L, 756L, 1053L, 566L), LowQualFinSF = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), GrLivArea = c(1710L, 1262L, 1786L, 1717L, 
    2198L, 1362L), BsmtFullBath = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    BsmtHalfBath = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), FullBath = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), HalfBath = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    BedroomAbvGr = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L), KitchenAbvGr = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), KitchenQual = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L), TotRmsAbvGrd = c(8L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 5L), Functional = structure(c(7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Maj1", "Maj2", "Min1", "Min2", 
    "Mod", "Sev", "Typ"), class = "factor"), Fireplaces = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), FireplaceQu = c(0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    0L), GarageType = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", 
    "2Types", "Attchd", "Basment", "BuiltIn", "CarPort", "Detchd"
    ), class = "factor"), GarageYrBlt = c(2003L, 1976L, 2001L, 
    1998L, 2000L, 1993L), GarageFinish = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L), GarageCars = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), GarageArea = c(548L, 
    460L, 608L, 642L, 836L, 480L), GarageQual = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), GarageCond = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), PavedDrive = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), WoodDeckSF = c(0L, 298L, 0L, 0L, 192L, 
    40L), OpenPorchSF = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), EnclosedPorch = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), `3SsnPorch` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), ScreenPorch = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PoolArea = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PoolQC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Fence = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), MiscFeature = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), MiscVal = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MoSold = c(2L, 
    5L, 9L, 2L, 12L, 10L), YrSold = c(2008L, 2007L, 2008L, 2006L, 
    2008L, 2009L), SaleType = structure(c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L), .Label = c("COD", "Con", "ConLD", "ConLI", "ConLw", 
    "CWD", "New", "Oth", "WD"), class = "factor"), SaleCondition = structure(c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Abnorml", "AdjLand", "Alloca", 
    "Family", "Normal", "Partial"), class = "factor"), SalePrice = c(208500L, 
    181500L, 223500L, 140000L, 250000L, 143000L)), .Names = c("Id", 
"MSSubClass", "MSZoning", "LotFrontage", "LotArea", "Street", 
"Alley", "LotShape", "LandContour", "Utilities", "LotConfig", 
"LandSlope", "Neighborhood", "Condition1", "Condition2", "BldgType", 
"HouseStyle", "OverallQual", "OverallCond", "YearBuilt", "YearRemodAdd", 
"RoofStyle", "RoofMatl", "Exterior1st", "Exterior2nd", "MasVnrType", 
"MasVnrArea", "ExterQual", "ExterCond", "Foundation", "BsmtQual", 
"BsmtCond", "BsmtExposure", "BsmtFinType1", "BsmtFinSF1", "BsmtFinType2", 
"BsmtFinSF2", "BsmtUnfSF", "TotalBsmtSF", "Heating", "HeatingQC", 
"CentralAir", "Electrical", "1stFlrSF", "2ndFlrSF", "LowQualFinSF", 
"GrLivArea", "BsmtFullBath", "BsmtHalfBath", "FullBath", "HalfBath", 
"BedroomAbvGr", "KitchenAbvGr", "KitchenQual", "TotRmsAbvGrd", 
"Functional", "Fireplaces", "FireplaceQu", "GarageType", "GarageYrBlt", 
"GarageFinish", "GarageCars", "GarageArea", "GarageQual", "GarageCond", 
"PavedDrive", "WoodDeckSF", "OpenPorchSF", "EnclosedPorch", "3SsnPorch", 
"ScreenPorch", "PoolArea", "PoolQC", "Fence", "MiscFeature", 
"MiscVal", "MoSold", "YrSold", "SaleType", "SaleCondition", "SalePrice"
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000026c0788>)
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you will need to include a portion of `train` to make your problem reproducible, so that others may help. Maybe use `dput(head(train))`. You can simplify you code by using `train[,  cols]` instead of `train[, which(names(train) %in% cols)]`

Comment: @RichardTelford Thanks, see updated post. regarding the suggestion to simplify my code using `train[, cols]` - that gives some errors: `Error in [.data.table(test, , cols) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'cols' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[,..cols] or DT[,cols,with=FALSE]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.`

Comment: I see - you are using a `data.table` - the syntax for these is different from `data.frames` (and I am not familiar with it). Unless your data are huge, I would stick to the standard `data.frame`

Comment: Not sure how to use data.frame instead. training set comes as CSV with headers which I load using `read.csv`

Comment: You should probably investigate your code enough to know why you have a `data.table` rather than `data.frame` - it would require loading the `data.table` package and `read.csv` produces a `data.frame` so some explicit conversion must have happened somewhere. Just for peace of mind.

Comment: As for your issue, to use a string vector of column names in `data.table`, you can add the `with = FALSE` argument to `[`. I'm going to mark as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15007979/903061) which covers that.