# Apply function on a subset of columns (.SDcols) whilst applying a different function on another column (within groups)

Tags: r, data.table, subset, lapply

This is very similar to a question applying a common function to multiple columns of a `data.table` uning `.SDcols` [answered thoroughly here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937165/using-dynamic-column-names-in-data-table?lq=1).

The difference is that I would like to simultaneously apply a different function on another column which is not part of the `.SD` subset.  I post a simple example below to show my attempt to solve the problem:

```
dt = data.table(grp = sample(letters[1:3],100, replace = TRUE),
                v1 = rnorm(100), 
                v2 = rnorm(100), 
                v3 = rnorm(100))
sd.cols = c("v2", "v3")
dt.out = dt[, list(v1 = sum(v1),  lapply(.SD,mean)), by = grp, .SDcols = sd.cols]
```

Yields the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , list(v1 = sum(v1), lapply(.SD, mean)), by = grp,  
: object 'v1' not found
```

Now this makes sense because the `v1` column is not included in the subset of columns which must be evaluated first.  So I explored further by including it in my subset of columns:

```
sd.cols = c("v1","v2", "v3")
dt.out = dt[, list(sum(v1), lapply(.SD,mean)), by = grp, .SDcols = sd.cols]
```

Now this does not cause an error but it provides an answer containing 9 rows (for 3 groups), with the sum repeated thrice in column `V1` and the means for all 3 columns (as expected but not wanted) placed in `V2` as shown below:

```
> dt.out 
   grp        V1                  V2
1:   c -1.070608 -0.0486639841313638
2:   c -1.070608  -0.178154270921521
3:   c -1.070608  -0.137625003604012
4:   b -2.782252 -0.0794929150464099
5:   b -2.782252  -0.149529237116445
6:   b -2.782252   0.199925178109264
7:   a  6.091355   0.141659419355985
8:   a  6.091355 -0.0272192037753071
9:   a  6.091355 0.00815760216214876
```

**Workaround Solution using 2 steps**

Clearly it is possible to solve the problem in multiple steps by calculating the `mean` by group for the subset of columns and joining it to the `sum` by group for the single column as follows:

```
dt.out1 = dt[, sum(v1), by = grp]
dt.out2 = dt[, lapply(.SD,mean), by = grp, .SDcols = sd.cols]
dt.out = merge(dt.out1, dt.out2, by = "grp")

> dt.out
   grp        V1         v2           v3
1:   a  6.091355 -0.0272192  0.008157602
2:   b -2.782252 -0.1495292  0.199925178
3:   c -1.070608 -0.1781543 -0.137625004
```

Im sure it's a fairly simple thing I am missing, thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: the fact that the first expression doesn't work is a bug imo, so please submit a bug report

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Update:** Issue [#495](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495) is solved now with [this recent commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/68091d851d400b4d768f3c41c0210da76945c12b), we can now do this just fine:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
set.seed(1L)
dt = data.table(grp = sample(letters[1:3],100, replace = TRUE),
                v1 = rnorm(100), 
                v2 = rnorm(100), 
                v3 = rnorm(100))
sd.cols = c("v2", "v3")
dt.out = dt[, list(v1 = sum(v1),  lapply(.SD,mean)), by = grp, .SDcols = sd.cols]
```

However note that in this case, `v2` would be returned as a list. That's because you're doing `list(val, list())` effectively. What you intend to do perhaps is:

```
dt[, c(list(v1=sum(v1)), lapply(.SD, mean)), by=grp, .SDcols = sd.cols]
#    grp        v1          v2         v3
# 1:   a -6.440273  0.16993940  0.2173324
# 2:   b  4.304350 -0.02553813  0.3381612
# 3:   c  0.377974 -0.03828672 -0.2489067
```

---

See history for older answer.

Comment: Arun, I don't think the `.SD` bottleneck applies in this case - the normal `.SD` bottleneck has to do with the overhead of `[.data.table`, which is absent here.

Comment: you're right, it *is* slower and I don't really understand why atm - I think this means that there is another large-overhead computation somewhere else (or put differently - I doubt that the bottleneck is calling eval from Cdogroups)

Comment: It's `eval` of `lapply` many times that is slow, not `.SD`. Look at the source of `base::lapply` at C level. It does it by constructing a `list(...)` call and then evaling that, anyway.  When `lapply` is looped, that same construction is done over and over, wastefully. So the optimization is to make that construction up front once (and at R level will do inside `[.data.table`) and then pass that to `dogroups`.  But only a straightforward single call to `lapply` is optimized currently. Combined with `c()` isn't picked up. cc @eddi

Comment: @MattDowle Hm, right and on point! just tried `system.time(dt[, c(bla = sum(y), lapply(1:5, mean)), by=x])` takes half of what it takes with `.SD` instead already! Seems that `lapply` is the culprit here..

Comment: This does not work on older versions of `data.table` i needed to upgrade the package, it does work on v1.9.8. My earlier version gave the error `object 'v1' not found`

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
dt[,list(sum(v1), mean(v2), mean(v3)), by=grp]
```

In `data.table`, using `list()` in the second argument allows you to describe a set of columns that result in the final `data.table`.

For what it's worth, `.SD` can be quite slow [^1] so you  may want to avoid it unless you truly need all of the data supplied in the subsetted `data.table` like you might for a more sophisticated function.

Another option, if you have many columns for `.SDcols` would be to do the merge in one line using the `data.table` merge syntax.

For example:

```
dt[, sum(v1), by=grp][dt[,lapply(.SD,mean), by=grp, .SDcols=sd.cols]]
```

In order to use the `merge` from `data.table`, you need to first use `setkey()` on your `data.table` so it knows how to match things up.

So really, first you need:

```
setkey(dt, grp)
```

Then you can use the line above to produce an equivalent result.

[^1]: I find this to be especially true as your number of groups approach the number of total rows. For example, this might happen where your key is an individual ID and many individuals have just one or two observations.

Comment: Using `wmean` proves a bit of a headache here as I would require the weighting column specified in the `.SDcols` portion even though I don't want to use it!  As I'm already using `sum` on that column it's a pain to also be calculating a `weighted.mean` on the column...

I guess I'd have to exclude that column BEFORE doing the `data.table` merge.