# data.table operations by column name

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a `data.table`

```
a <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2,3),a=21:25,b=11:15,key="id")
```

I can add new columns like this:

```
a[, sa := sum(a), by="id"]
a[, sb := sum(b), by="id"]
> a
   id  a  b sa sb
1:  1 21 11 43 23
2:  1 22 12 43 23
3:  2 23 13 47 27
4:  2 24 14 47 27
5:  3 25 15 25 15
```

However, suppose that I have *column names* instead:

```
for (n in c("a","b")) {
  s <- paste0("s",n)
  a[, s := sum(n), by="id", with=FALSE] # ERROR: invalid 'type' (character) of argument
}
```

what do I do?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16617226/324364

Comment: And a bit older: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12392269/1412059

Comment: ...and 1.6 from the data.table FAQ.

Comment: @joran: I don't see how I could use `eval`/`quote` here; I tried `s <- quote(paste0("s..",n) := sum(n)); a[, eval(s), by="id"]` and failed.

Comment: @sds I was just brainstorming. I sympathize, though. The level of confusion data.table creates for me with this type of problem is the single biggest reason I don't use it more often.

Comment: @joran Then I hope my answer and comments help?

Comment: @MattDowle It's my problem, I'm too dumb. I deal better with syntax designed for stupid people.

Comment: @joran Do you have any suggestions? Or even any other way to add/update columns by reference by group? Let alone where those columns are defined in a variable. It's `DT[where, select|update, by]`. It can be restricted to subset of rows just by supplying `where` too.  Do you know SQL?

Comment: @MattDowle: which should I use - your method (`get`) or @eddi's (`lapply`/`.SD`)? (I upvoted both, but I am now torn between them)

Comment: @MattDowle I do know quite a lot of SQL. I'm not criticizing, I'm just saying that it pretty routinely makes me feel quite dumb. And the ease with which other people seem to have with it leads me to conclude that the problem is me, not data.table.

Comment: @joran I'm British so I read it as sarcasm. Like : https://twitter.com/Cafe_Global/status/417978158470930432/photo/1

Comment: @sds  Eddi's is the best as it avoids grouping many times. That's the one to accept.  Great question btw.

Comment: @MattDowle: I thought so too, but your version finished in 36 seconds, while his is still running (5+ minutes). The funny thing is that your version suggests his: "'get' found in j. xvars being set to all columns. Use .SDcols or eval(macro) instead. Both will detect the columns used which is important for efficiency."

Comment: @sds that's curious - can you post a larger dataset where you see that, when I test on something like `N = 1e7; a = data.table(id = 1:N, a = sample(N), b = sample(N))`, `.SD` version is much faster

Comment: @eddi: your data set has _trivial_ `.SD` (one line!)

Comment: @sds sure, but the bottleneck in these scenarios is large number of groups and not size of `.SD`; anyway, testing on `id = sample(1:1e4, N, T)` again results in `.SD` being several times faster - so I'm curious what the dimensions of your data are and if you can come up with a simple similar example

Comment: @eddi: my `.SDcols` is not the same as all the columns (as opposed to the examples here). my data is `Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 3693671 obs. of  10 variables:`

Comment: @sds Sounds like we should investigate this further.  Can you construct a dataset and show the exact two commands so that we can take a look?

Comment: @MattDowle: I have the data set. where do you want me to upload it? shouldn't we move this discussion somewhere? (mailing list?)

Comment: @sds Haven't tried it myself but how about http://www.filedropper.com/.  A new question on S.O. would be best. This question was "how". New question would be something like "why is one of these commands slower", linking to this question.

Comment: @sds But a randomly generated dataset would be even better, like eddi's example above.

Comment: @joran, probably you should start by asking questions on things you don't understand here on S.O. or on data.table mailing list then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
a <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2,3),a=21:25,b=11:15,key="id")

a[, c("sa", "sb") := lapply(.SD, sum), by = id]
```

Or slightly more generally:

```
cols.to.sum = c("a", "b")
a[, paste0("s", cols.to.sum) := lapply(.SD, sum), by = id, .SDcols = cols.to.sum]
```

Comment: +1 Even better as that does it in a single grouping, rather than a grouping for each column being added one by one. Using `.SD` in this case shouldn't bite, because all the data inside `.SD` is being used.

Comment: @MattDowle as an aside - the main bite from using `.SD` happens when `[.data.table` is involved because of the huge overhead of that function, so something like `.SD[1:.N]` would be orders of magnitude slower in a "by" loop that `.SD`

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for reminder. It's on the list to optimize that.

Comment: @eddi, just to remind [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20460441/559784) discussion as well. It's not just `[.data.table`. It certainly gets things slow. But just evaluating `.SD` also seems to get things slow. I'll make a proper benchmark to test this with data.frame and data.table and post back.

Answer (score 8):

This is similar to :

[How to generate a linear combination of variables and update table using data.table in a loop call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808374/how-to-generate-a-linear-combination-of-variables-and-update-table-using-data-ta)

but you want to combine this with `by=` too,  so `set()` isn't flexible enough. That's a deliberate design design and `set()` is unlikely to change in that regard.

I sometimes use the `EVAL` helper at the end of that answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20808573/403310 
 Some wince at that approach but I just think of it like constructing a dynamic SQL statement, which is quite common practice. The `EVAL` approach gives ultimate flexibility without head scratching about `eval()` and `quote()`. To see the dynamic query that's been constructed (to check it) you can add a `print` inside your `EVAL` helper function.

However, in this simple example you can wrap the LHS of `:=` with brackets to tell `data.table` to lookup the value (clearer than `with=FALSE`), and the RHS needs a `get()`.

```
for (n in c("a","b")) {
  s <- paste0("s",n)
  a[, (s) := sum(get(n)), by="id"]
}
```

Comment: I don't need the parens around `s`, do I?

Comment: Yes otherwise it's going to create a column called `"s"` in both iterations of the loop.

Comment: Oh sorry - I missed the `with=FALSE`.  We've moved towards `(LHS):=` because that's easier to read.  `with=FALSE` is unclear whether it refers to the LHS or the RHS of `:=`.

Comment: That reminds me,  we should formally deprecate `with=FALSE` when `:=` is used.

Comment: Right so very little wrong is the question.  Just wrapping `n` with `get(n)` was all that was needed. The error was from `sum("a")`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit 2020-02-15 about `..`

`data.table` also supports the `..` syntax to "look up a level", obviating the need for `with=FALSE` in most cases, e.g. `dt[ , ..n1]` and `dt[ , ..n2]` in the below

---

have a look at `with` in `? data.table`:

```
dt <- data.table(id=1:5,a=21:25,b=11:15,key="id")
dt[, n3 := dt[ , n1, with = FALSE ] * dt[ , n2, with = FALSE ], with = FALSE ]
```

*EDIT:*

Or you just change the colnames forth and back:

```
dt <- data.table(id=1:5,a=21:25,b=11:15,key="id")
dt[ , dt.names["n3"] := 1L, with = FALSE ]

dt.names <- c( n1 = "a", n2 = "b", n3 = "c" )
setnames( dt, dt.names, names(dt.names) )

dt[ , n3 := n1 * n2, by = "id" ]
setnames( dt, names(dt.names), dt.names )
```

which works together with by.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that does the call mangling and avoids any overhead with `.SD`

```
# a helper function
makeCall <- function(x,fun) bquote(.(fun)(.(x)))
# the columns you wish to sum (apply function to)
cols <- c('a','b')
new.cols <- paste0('s',cols)
# create named list of names
name.cols <- setNames(sapply(cols,as.name), new.cols)
# create the call
my_call <-  as.call(c(as.name(':='), lapply(name.cols, makeCall, fun = as.name('sum'))))
(a[, eval(my_call), by = 'id'])

#    id  a  b sa sb
# 1:  1 21 11 43 23
# 2:  1 22 12 43 23
# 3:  2 23 13 47 27
# 4:  2 24 14 47 27
# 5:  3 25 15 25 15
```