# Change data.table column classes to integer64, double respectively

Tags: r, data.table

Given data.table dt:

```
dt <- structure(list(V1 = c("1544018118438041139", "1544018118466235879", 
"1544018118586849680", "1544018118601169211", "1544018118612947335", 
"1544018118614422179"), V2 = c("162", "162", "161.05167", "158.01309", 
"157", "157"), V3 = c("38", "38", "36.051697", "33.01306", "32", 
"32"), V4 = c("0.023529414", "0.025490198", "0.023529414", "0.027450982", 
"0.03137255", "0.03137255"), V5 = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1"), V6 = c("2131230815", "2131230815", "2131230815", "2131230815", 
"2131230815", "2131230815"), V7 = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"-1")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2715f60>)
```

I want the first column to be `bit64::as.integer64()` and the rest of the columns `as.numeric()`

I am trying to do this:

```
dt <- dt[ ,V1 := bit64::as.integer64(V1)]

dt[, lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = -c("V1")]
```

But it doesn't seem to do what I want, please advise how to change specific columns to class A(`integer64`) and the rest to another class B (say `as.numeric()`)?

Comment: But I want it to be first column and rest of the columns, I can't guarantee that I will get these columns names always, I want it to be general. @markus

Comment: Again @markus first column not "V1"

Comment: `.SDcols = setdiff(names(dt), names(dt)[1])`

Comment: Still doesn't work, it shows the first column as int64 but the rest still char, maybe I need to inject with = FALSE? @markus

Comment: You need to do `dt <- dt[, lapply(...]` but not in the first case because with `:=` you change the `V1` column by reference.

Comment: @markus would you be so kind to explain what does it mean by change column by reference?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html under **b) The `:=` operator**

Comment: And it still doesn't work....please post the whole solution that works for you. I am getting V2 - V7 without V1 @markus

Comment: Take a look at [Apply function on a subset of columns (.SDcols) whilst applying a different function on another column (within groups)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459519/apply-function-on-a-subset-of-columns-sdcols-whilst-applying-a-different-func)

Comment: @markus tried it already, it didn't work. dt[, c(list(V1 = as.integer64(V1), lapply(.SD, as.numeric))), .SDcols = setdiff(names(dt), names(dt)[1])]

Comment: Does this work? `dt[, names(dt)[-1] := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = names(dt)[-1]]`

Comment: @MikeH. yes sure, it works - all cols besides the first one became dbl, the first one is still char

Comment: @MikeH. please explain the solution

Comment: @MikeH. Please be so kind and help me to understand how to deal with these big 19 digits numbers in R, I have tried gmp package and bit64 but when I run it my R crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, @dirk_eddelbuettel I managed to do this:

1) Load all the `JSON` files (in my case) and use

```
bigint_as_char=TRUE
```

within `fromJSON` command.

2) Now you have a big table with all columns as characters.

3) Convert timestamp column to `bit64::as.integer64()` - you get the numbers I want.

4) Convert the rest to desired types.

5) When I want to perform calculations, for example `timestamp - lag(timestamp)` I am adding the `lag_timestamp = lag(timestamp)` (with `dplyr::mutate`) as new column and add `diff_column` = storing it `as.character()`

6) You are almost done - the new diff column stores the value I want as string / character and now you can convert it to `as.numeric()` where needed or apply `ifelse()` to deal with non relevant values.

7) That's all, it works perfectly for me and don't crash R Studio.

Before applying my solution R Studio crashed.

Comment: JSON? _shudders_ Textconversion is slow, in essence your answer is the same as mine as you to have to resort to a helper package.

Comment: Just a little promo, I am a data scientist that perform first research using files in AWS S3.
Afterwards I don't need to deal with it because ETL professionals provide me with relational db with all columns I need. I just connect to it and skip the data preparation stage.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments above it seems like you want to be able to do this all in one step rather than convert the first to `integer64` and then the rest to `double`. One way you can do this is with:

```
dt[, names(dt) := Map(function(fun, x) fun(x), rep(list(bit64::as.integer64, as.numeric), times = c(1,length(.SD) - 1)), .SD), .SDcols = names(dt)]
```

The `Map` function iterates through your inputs together. That is, it takes the first elements of your first and second vectors and pass them as arguments to our function. Then it takes the second elements of both vectors and passes those to the function.

In our `Map` call we have:

- A **main function** to apply. This is an anonymous function which takes two arugments (1) `fun`, and (2) `x`. The result of our function is the result of applying `fun` to `x` or `fun(x)`. For a concrete example try:

  ```
  myfun <- function(fun, x){
    fun(x)
  }
  res<-myfun(as.numeric, c("1","1")); class(res)
  ```
- A list of functions to pass to our **main function**. These will be used as `fun` in our **main function**. In this case its `list(as.integer64, as.numeric, as.numeric,...)`
- A list of vectors to pass to our **main function**. These will be used as `x` in our **main function**. In this case each column of our `dt`.

A quick and dirty visual aid of how this works is (assuming `custom_function` takes two arguments):

[image]

Comment: @steves let me know if its unclear. I think I might add a graphic about `Map`

Comment: it super clear!!!! 
You definitely solved this kind of issues I have but the biggest issue for me is still to deal with these big 19 digits timestamp numbers. I have tried almost anything but nothing helped me to deal with these big numbers without loosing the precision.
Maybe I can show you my issues somehow, maybe you've already saw same issues.

Comment: @steves im sorry its hard to say without seeing specifics. This might be better as a new question. Also I don't have as much experience storing large numbers. Maybe consider taking the log or some transformation as well?

Comment: These are nanosecond timestamps. All transformation, including casting to double, loose information.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel please have a look on my answer, I managed to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you have a data.table object with `integer64` nanosecond timestamps since the epoch. I use the same at work to represent high-resolution timestamps.

The good news is that data.table supports this -- by relying on our package [nanotime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nanotime) which itself uses [bit64](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nanotime) for the `integer64` type. However, I create my timestamps differently, typically from compiled code where I retrieve the data.

I described this in some detail at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/)  in [this post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/creating-integer64-and-nanotime-vectors/) .  So some good news: this can be done.  Some bad news: I don't think you can do it the way you want it because we can only go via `double` which has only 16 decimals precision, not 19.  But maybe I am missing trick so if simpler solution exists I'd be all ears. (And I keep forgetting if there is a 'parse int64 from string approach'. I never went that route because you can't do that at scale -- I deal with pretty sizeable data sets too.)

Comment: I managed to do this, please see my answer. @dirk_eddelbuettel