# Mean of list of coumns by group

Tags: r, data.table

I want to compute the mean of several columns for each group, but the columns should be given as a vector of names:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(k=c(1,1,2,2,2),v=1:5,w=11:15,key="k")
DT[,list(N=.N,v=mean(v),w=mean(w)),by="k"]
   k N   v    w
1: 1 2 1.5 11.5
2: 2 3 4.0 14.0
```

However, I don't want to specify `v` and `w` explicitly when computing means.
I have another variable

```
mycols <- c("v","w")
```

which should be used instead of explicit column names.

I tried various versions of

```
DT[,list(.N,colMeans(.SD[mycols])),by="k"]
```

and got

```
Error in `[.data.table`(.SD, mycols) :
```

I wonder if there is a way to do it...

Comment: You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937165/using-dynamic-column-names-in-data-table) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833247/how-can-one-work-fully-generically-in-data-table-in-r-with-column-names-in-varia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can concatenate `.N` with the means using `.SDcols` to choose the columns `mycols`. We'll also want to use `lapply(.SD, mean)` instead of `colMeans(.SD)` as `colMeans()` is [not optimized](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Do's-and-Don'ts#5-dont-use-colsums-use-lapply-on-sd).

```
DT[, c(N = .N, lapply(.SD, mean)), by = k, .SDcols = mycols]
#    k N   v    w
# 1: 1 2 1.5 11.5
# 2: 2 3 4.0 14.0
```

So another example of this would be, if we only want `"v"` we use `mycols[1]`

```
DT[, c(N = .N, lapply(.SD, mean)), by = k, .SDcols = mycols[1]]
#    k N   v
# 1: 1 2 1.5
# 2: 2 3 4.0
```

To illustrate further, if we add a column `z` then run the same code from above, then we see that `z` is not included in the result.  This is because it was removed from `.SD` using `.SDcols = mycols`.

```
DT[, z := 21:25]
DT[, c(N = .N, lapply(.SD, mean)), by = k, .SDcols = mycols]
#    k N   v    w
# 1: 1 2 1.5 11.5
# 2: 2 3 4.0 14.0
```

Comment: I have other columns (besides `v` & `w`) which I do not want to include.

Comment: @sds - Right. That is what `.SDcols` is for. It chooses the columns for `.SD`.  If we add the column `DT$z <- 21:25` then run the code above we can see that `z` will not be included in the result nor the calculation

Comment: Added that example into my answer

Comment: thanks - how is `.(N=.N)` different from `N=.N`?

Comment: thanks; it appears to be unnecessary though in this case.

Comment: @sds -  ah yes, you're right.  Not in this case.  Disregard that :)