# Pass column name and group argument as variables in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'm trying to count the number of users for different cohorts. I found  a way to do it using dplyr, but I'd like to implement a solution using data.table, so to improve efficiency and as an exercise.

Libraries that I'm using for this example:

```
   library(dplyr)
   library(magrittr)
   library(data.table)
```

Let's say that I have this df:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 11, TRUE), 
                 V2 = sample(c("2016", "2017", "2018"), 11, TRUE),
                 V3 = sample(seq(1:3), 11, TRUE), 
                 V4 = sample(seq(1:3), 11, TRUE),
                 Id = sample(seq(1:5), 11, TRUE))
```

The solution using `dplyr` would be:

```
for (grp in c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")) {
    col <- paste0(grp, "_user_cnt")
    df %<>%
    group_by_(grp) %>%
    mutate(!!col := n_distinct(Id)) %>%
    ungroup()
}
```

And my approach with data.table would be something like this:

```
DT <- data.table(df)
for (grp in c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")) {
    col <- paste0(grp, "_user_cnt")
    DT[, (deparse(col)) := n_distinct(Id), by = get(grp)]
}
```

The problem is that I don't find the way to pass the `col` and the `grp` properly, this way computes everything right, but the colnames are quoted, which is nasty and leads to errors. I've tried the techniques suggested [here](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#passing-datatable-column-names-as-function-arguments), and the answer and comments of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603890/pass-column-name-in-data-table-using-variable). But none of them seems to work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can get the desired results simply with `DT[, (col) := n_distinct(Id), by = grp]`. You get quotes because `deparse(col)` evaluates to something like "`"V1_user_cnt"`" (the inner quote is part of the string).

Comment: With data.table, there's uniqueN instead of n_distinct