# Quasiquotation with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rlang, quasiquotes

I'm trying to wrap my head around quasiquotation so that I could use it together with a `data.table` call. Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
library(rlang)
dt <- data.table(col1 = 1:10, col2 = 11:20)

dt[, col1]
```

If I wanted to wrap this into function, how would I do this? I tried:

```
foo <- function(dt, col) {
  col <- quo(col)

  expr(dt[, !!col1])
}

foo(dt, col1)
```

But get `Error in enexpr(expr) : object 'col1' not found`. I assume I'm missing some steps as `data.table` evaluates this differently than `dplyr`.

Comment: if at all you need to pass a symbol rather than a character, just use `substitute` then transform to character then use the double period format to subset from the main datatable

Comment: maybe `foo <- function(dt, col) dt[, eval(substitute(col))]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to capture the column name as a symbol with

```
col <- ensym(col)
```

rather than `quo()` and then use

```
expr(dt[, !!col])
```

(not `col1` which doesn't exist there) but that will just return an expression. If you want to evaluated it, you'd need

```
eval_tidy(expr(dt[, !!col]))
```

But really the quasinotation stuff works best in the tidyverse and not with data.table functions natively. The "data.table" way might be more like something in this existing question: [Pass column name in data.table using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603890/pass-column-name-in-data-table-using-variable). data.table very much prefers strings to symbols.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! `col1` was a typo but `ensym` was the key here :)

Comment: I get what you are saying about the *"data.table" way* but the linked answer doesn't seem to work anymore. I thought about the strings vs. symbols argument but I had a lot of problems using `with = FALSE`, which is why I wanted to learn quasinotation in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `deparse` and `substitute` and use the argument `with=FALSE` as in :

```
foo <- function(dt, col){
  col_str = deparse(substitute(col))
  dt[, col_str, with = F]
}
```

or you can use `eval` and `substitute` and use the default data.table argument `with=TRUE` as in :

```
foo <- function(dt, col){
  col_symb = substitute(col)
  dt[, eval(col_symb)] # by default: with=TRUE
}
```

In both cases, `substitute` will get the *name* of the argument that you pass to the parameter `col`. In the first case `deparse` will convert this name as a string, thus enabling us to select it from the data.table using with = FALSE. In the second case we evaluate (using `eval`) the *name* of the argument in the context of the data.table.

Comment: the aim is to pass a symbol. not a string

Comment: thanks but this will only work if `col` is a string and with more complicated operations I found out there are additional problems

Comment: I fix my answer accordingly

Comment: This looks promising now. But why is `as.symbol` outside the function? This defeats the purpose of the whole quasiquotation, doesn't it?

Comment: Ok I thought the variable was already a symbol, I fix accordingly.