# How to use R data.table column names with cube(..., j = ,...) within a function?

Tags: r, data.table

I can obtain a summary of a variable stratified by other variables as follows:

```
require(data.table)

DT <- data.table(mtcars)

var_work <- "hp"
by_vars <- c("cyl", "carb")

ans_1 <- cube(DT, j = as.list(quantile(get(var_work))), by = by_vars)

ans_1
    cyl carb  0%    25%   50%    75% 100%
 1:   6    4 110 110.00 116.5 123.00  123
 2:   4    1  65  66.00  66.0  93.00   97
 3:   6    1 105 106.25 107.5 108.75  110
 4:   8    2 150 150.00 162.5 175.00  175
 5:   8    4 205 218.75 237.5 245.00  264
 6:   4    2  52  69.25  93.0 105.50  113
 7:   8    3 180 180.00 180.0 180.00  180
 8:   6    6 175 175.00 175.0 175.00  175
 9:   8    8 335 335.00 335.0 335.00  335
10:   6   NA 105 110.00 110.0 123.00  175
11:   4   NA  52  65.50  91.0  96.00  113
12:   8   NA 150 176.25 192.5 241.25  335
13:  NA    4 110 123.00 210.0 241.25  264
14:  NA    1  65  66.00  93.0 101.00  110
15:  NA    2  52  92.00 111.0 150.00  175
16:  NA    3 180 180.00 180.0 180.00  180
17:  NA    6 175 175.00 175.0 175.00  175
18:  NA    8 335 335.00 335.0 335.00  335
19:  NA   NA  52  96.50 123.0 180.00  335
```

Next, I would like to write a helper function implementing exactly what is shown above, which however produces the error:

```
my_fun <- function(table_work, var_w, by_v) {

    tab_out <- cube(table_work, j = as.list(quantile(get(var_w))), by = by_v)
    return(tab_out)

}

ans_2 <- my_fun(table_work = DT, var_w = var_work, by_v = by_vars)

Error in get(var_w) : object 'var_w' not found
```

I have searched for the answer some relevant blogs (e.g., [Advanced tips and tricks with data.table](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#passing-datatable-column-names-as-function-arguments)) and posts (e.g., by [Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603890/pass-column-name-in-data-table-using-variable), [frankc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/select-assign-to-data-table-when-variable-names-are-stored-in-a-character-vect) etc.), and tried different combinations of quote(), eval(), get(), assign() etc. within "my_fun", but nothing worked for me.

The question is: How should I correct "my_fun" helper function so it works and produces the same result as ans_1?

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.2-18     fst_0.9.0         data.table_1.12.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1  parallel_3.6.1  Rcpp_1.0.3      grid_3.6.1      lattice_0.20-38
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When reading through the code for `data.table:::cube.data.table` and `data.table:::groupingsets.data.table`, the `j` argument is already being evaluated using NSE. Hence, being unable to pass in `as.name(var_work)` to the environment argument of `substitute`, the function will fail.

As a workaround, you can use `.SDcols`:

```
library(data.table)    
DT <- data.table(mtcars)    
var_work <- "hp"
by_vars <- c("cyl", "carb")

my_fun <- function(table_work, var_w, by_v) {
    cube(table_work, j=as.list(quantile(.SD[[1L]])), by=by_v, .SDcols=var_w)
}

ans_2 <- my_fun(table_work = DT, var_w = var_work, by_v = by_vars)
```

Comment: @jangorecki is the best person to answer this question imo. if he comes along, i will be glad to delete this answer

Comment: it works, thanks. Still, why cube(), and I guess other functions, cannot see 'var_w' even though it is explicitly declared within "my_fun"?

Comment: `var_w` is visible in the scope of `my_fun`. however, it is passed as `jj = substitute(j)` into `cube.data.table` and `groupingsets.data.table`, and `jj` is `eval` in the scope of the `groupingsets.data.table` which does not have `var_w`.

Comment: Just came across this Q, pinging my username didn't work AFAICT. This is good workaround. Of course we are open for suggestions or improvement if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can always compute on the language:

```
my_fun <- function(table_work, var_w, by_v) {

  var_w <- as.name(var_w)
  eval(bquote(cube(table_work, j = as.list(quantile(.(var_w))), by = by_v)))  

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a tidyverse solution using https://tbradley1013.github.io/2018/10/01/calculating-quantiles-for-groups-with-dplyr-summarize-and-purrr-partial/

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- c(0, 0.25,.5,.75,1)

p_names <- map_chr(p, ~str_c(.x*100, "%"))

p_funs <- map(p, ~partial(quantile, probs = ., na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  set_names(nm = p_names)


my_pipe <- function(df,group_by_what,quantile_at){
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!!group_by_what) %>% 
    summarize_at(quantile_at,p_funs)
}

var_work <- vars(hp)

by_vars <- vars(cyl,carb)

my_pipe(mtcars,group_by_what = by_vars,quantile_at = var_work)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 7
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  carb  `0%` `25%` `50%` `75%` `100%`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     4     1    65  66     66    93      97
#> 2     4     2    52  69.2   93   106.    113
#> 3     6     1   105 106.   108.  109.    110
#> 4     6     4   110 110    116.  123     123
#> 5     6     6   175 175    175   175     175
#> 6     8     2   150 150    162.  175     175
#> 7     8     3   180 180    180   180     180
#> 8     8     4   205 219.   238.  245     264
#> 9     8     8   335 335    335   335     335

# Easy to extend

var_work <- vars(hp,wt)

my_pipe(mtcars,group_by_what = by_vars,quantile_at = var_work)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 12
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  carb `hp_0%` `wt_0%` `hp_25%` `wt_25%` `hp_50%` `wt_50%` `hp_75%`
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     4     1      65    1.84     66       1.94      66      2.2       93 
#> 2     4     2      52    1.51     69.2     1.75      93      2.46     106.
#> 3     6     1     105    3.22    106.      3.28     108.     3.34     109.
#> 4     6     4     110    2.62    110       2.81     116.     3.16     123 
#> 5     6     6     175    2.77    175       2.77     175      2.77     175 
#> 6     8     2     150    3.44    150       3.44     162.     3.48     175 
#> 7     8     3     180    3.73    180       3.76     180      3.78     180 
#> 8     8     4     205    3.17    219.      3.64     238.     4.54     245 
#> 9     8     8     335    3.57    335       3.57     335      3.57     335 
#> # … with 3 more variables: `wt_75%` <dbl>, `hp_100%` <dbl>, `wt_100%` <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think your answer kind of misses the point. Max wants to learn the data.table way.