Confused about scope of R data.table cube()
I'm a bit confused about the data.table::cube() (and by extension, rollup(), groupingsets(). It seems like the function argument does not end up in the same scope as the call to cube().
Why does my second example below not work? And how would I pass cube() a function, if not like that?
library(data.table)
dataurl <- "https://jozefhajnala.gitlab.io/r/post/data/"
flights <- readRDS(url(paste0(dataurl, "r006/flights.rds")))
flights <- as.data.table(flights)[month < 3]

# Works
summary_fn = mean
cubed <- data.table::cube(
  flights,
  .(distance = summary_fn(distance)),
  by = c("month", "origin")
)

print(cubed)
rm(summary_fn)

# Does not work
cube_fn = function(summary_fn) {
  cubed <- data.table::cube(
    flights,
    .(distance = summary_fn(distance)),
    by = c("month", "origin")
  )
}

print(cube_fn(mean))


Error in summary_fn(distance) : could not find function "summary_fn"


Interesting, in 2nd version assigning directly within the function doesn't work either: summary_fn <- mean

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622907/how-to-use-r-data-table-column-names-with-cube-j-within-a-function

Do you get an error message? (The phrase “does not work” conveys no information. )

@IRTFM Added the error message.

@lotus Thanks, I had seen that, I suppose that the two are related, but I'm still not sure how I'd pass a function.

@Matt - you will need to use something like eval(substitute(cube(flights, .(distance = summary_fn(distance)), by = c("month", "origin")), list(summary_fn = summary_fn))) in your function body.

I wonder if it would succeed if you assigned the data.table environment to your function?

@lotus Thanks that does work, though eval statements make me a bit uneasy!

@IRTFM That sounds interesting, do you know where I might find the documentation?

?environment<-
