# How do I loop through stock/mutual fund data in R

Tags: r, loops, stock

I can download stock/mutual fund data in R using tidyquant/quantmod; however, I need it in a format that a 3rd party application can read.

The download comes in this format:

Date        FSAIX.Open FSAIX.High FSAIX.Low FSAIX.Close FSAIX.Volume FSAIX.Adjusted

12/16/1985      10        10         10        10            0           1.995289

However, I need it in this format:

Date               Open      High       Low       Close

12/16/1985      1.995289   1.995289   1.995289  1.995289

Notice that "FSAIX.Adjusted" became the Open, High, Low, and Close price on this day. Which, is fine since FSAIX is a mutual fund and only "trades" at one price each day. (For those curious the "_______.Adjusted" price means the closing price adjusted for splits, dividends, or distributions)

I have been able to 'hard code' R to give me data for one stock/mutual fund at a time. Here is my code:

```
##################################
library(tidyquant)
library(data.table)

# symbol list to download
fid_symbol <- c("FSAIX","FSAVX")

# Download symbol's data from yahoo finance
getSymbols(fid_symbol,src = 'yahoo',from = "1970-01-01", to = "2020-07-22")

# Change XTS file into a data table for both formatting
##    and easier to export with the date included 
my_DT <- as.data.table(FSAIX)

# Make new columns in the data table
my_DT[,"Open":=FSAIX.Adjusted]
my_DT[,"High":=FSAIX.Adjusted]
my_DT[,"Low":=FSAIX.Adjusted]
my_DT[,"Close":=FSAIX.Adjusted]

# Delete old clumns in the data table
my_DT <- my_DT[,-c(2:7)]

#Change index column name to date
setnames(my_DT,old="index",new="Date")

# write file to working directory
fwrite(my_DT,file = "FSAIX.csv")
#################################
```

This does give the desired output for the hard coded symbol - FSAIX. Yeah me!, I thought at first. But then the problems began when I tried to loop through a list, more than the 2 in the example, of mutual fund (stock) symbols. :-/  I have hit a brick wall for the last 1.5 weeks...

I recently tried to "replicate" some code I found on quantstrattrader's website, https://quantstrattrader.wordpress.com/2018/09/17/principal-component-momentum/  after a number of failed attempts on my own, and this code worked:

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
require(quantmod)
require(stats)
require(xts)
 
symbols <- c("SPY", "EFA", "EEM", "DBC", "HYG", "GLD", "IEF", "TLT")  
 
# get free data from yahoo
rets <- list()
getSymbols(symbols, src = 'yahoo', from = '1990-12-31')
for(i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  returns <- Return.calculate(Ad(get(symbols[i])))
  colnames(returns) <- symbols[i]
  rets[[i]] <- returns
}
rets <- na.omit(do.call(cbind, rets))
```

However, when I tried modify this to my needs it did not work. Here is my latest example:

```
### Fidelity Funds Dowload Script...

library(tidyquant)
library(data.table)

# symbol list to download
fid_symbol <- c("FSAIX","FSAVX")

# Download symbol's data from yahoo finance
getSymbols(fid_symbol,src = 'yahoo',from = "1970-01-01", to = "2020-07-22")

# My 'loop' to get the symbols in fid_symbol
for (i in 1:length(fid_symbol) )
{
  # make data table
  my_DT<- as.data.table(fid_symbol[[i]])
  # get symbol from fid_symbol
  sym <- fid_symbol[[i]]
  
  # make new columns and delete old
  my_DT[,"Open":=sym.Adjusted]
  my_DT[,"High":=sym.Adjusted]
  my_DT[,"Low":=sym.Adjusted]
  my_DT[,"Close":=sym.Adjusted]
  my_DT <- my_DT[,-c(2:7)]
 
  # Change index column name to date

  setnames(my_DT,old="index",new="Date")

  # write file to working directory

  fwrite(my_DT,file = paste0(sym,'.csv'))
}

################################
```

This most recent failed_attempt_11.0 gave the following error when run:
" Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) :
object 'sym.Adjusted' not found  "

I have also tried to write this technique as a function and use the "apply" family and that also failed....

Thank you for any help or suggestions in advance!
Cheers, Chris

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603890/pass-column-name-in-data-table-using-variable), can you use something like `col_name <- paste0(fid_symbol[[i]], ".Adjusted")` and then `my_DT[, "Open":=get(col_name)]` in your last example?

Comment: Thank you for the kind suggestion, but this just produced the error: " Error in get(col_name) : object 'FSAIX.Adjusted' not found "

Comment: Thank you for the kind suggestion, but this just produced the error: " Error in get(col_name) : object 'FSAIX.Adjusted' not found "   It appears that the problem is with { my_DT<- as.data.table(fid_symbol[[i]]) } this is returning just the character "FSAIX" and not taking the XTS object and making it into a data table!