# Filter by column index number data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

Interesting I am unable to find a way to filter using the column number. I do not know the name of the column because it changes name, but I always know the position of the column.

This seems pretty trivial but it seems like I can only reference the i portion using the column name.

```
table = data.table(one = c(1,2,3), two = c("a","b","c"))

> table
   one two
1:   1   a
2:   2   b
3:   3   c
```

I do not know that the second column is "two". I just want to filter by second column.

```
> table[two == "a"]
   one two
1:   1   a
```

UPDATE:

As Ronak described, I could use

```
> table[table[[2]]=="a"]

   one two
1:   1   a
```

However I would next like to update this same column, for example I would like to turn "a" into "c".

what I need:

```
> table
   one two
1:   1   c
2:   2   b
3:   3   c
```

I have tried:

```
> table[table[[2]]=="a", table[[2]]:= "c"]
> table
   one two    a    b    c
1:   1   a    c    c    c
2:   2   b <NA> <NA> <NA>
3:   3   c <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

So it seems like I am taking all the values in the second column and creating new columns for them instead of just changing the filtered rows to c.

```
> table[table[[2]]=="a", table[2]:= "c"]

Error in `[.data.table`(table, table[[2]] == "a", `:=`(table[2], "c")) : 
  LHS of := must be a symbol, or an atomic vector (column names or positions).
```

So I think I need to know the position of the second column.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I was actually editing it as you posted this!

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12391950/680068 https://stackoverflow.com/q/12603890/680068

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `[[` works :

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 2:6)
dt[dt[[1]] == 1]

#   a b
#1: 1 2
```

This gives the same output as `dt[a == 1]`.

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you. I have updated the question to add that I would need to perform operations on this same column.

Comment: @JantjeHouten You can use `table[table[[2]]=="a", (2) := "c"]`

Answer (score 2):

As we know we need the 2nd column, get the 2nd column name, and use "variable as column name", see example:

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(one = c(1,2,3), two = c("a","b","c"))

# get the 2nd column name
myCol <- colnames(d)[ 2 ]

# subset
d[ get(myCol) == "a", ]

# subset and update
d[ get(myCol) == "a", (myCol) := "c" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `.SD`

```
dt[dt[, .SD[[1]] == 1]]
#   a b
#1: 1 2
```

#### data

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 2:6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
table[[2]][table[[2]]=="a"] <- "c"
table
> table
   one two
1:   1   c
2:   2   b
3:   3   c
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out:

```
> table[table[[2]]=="a", colnames(table)[2]:= "c"]
> table
   one two
1:   1   c
2:   2   b
3:   3   c
```

Thanks!