# Pass/loop over column names to data.table and ggplot as variables

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, data.table

One problem I often have with `data.table` and `ggplot` is their use in a for loop, in which I iterate over a set of column names.

Take this data table as example:

```
dt <- data.table(values1=rep(c(1,2),each=2),
                 values2=rep(c(10,20),each=2),
                 notthis=0,
                 category=rep(c('a','b'),each=2))
##
##    values1 values2 notthis category
## 1:       1      10       0        a
## 2:       1      10       0        a
## 3:       2      20       0        b
## 4:       2      20       0        b
```

Let's say I want to iterate over all columns of `dt` except `notthis` and `category`. For each column I want to plot two histogram of its values, according to `category`, and add a vertical line representing their mean values (possibly passing the plots to a pdf device using `pdf`, `print`, `dev.off`).

An idea of code could be as follows:

```
loopnames <- setdiff(colnames(dt), c('notthis', 'category'))
## [1] "values1" "values2"

for(ZZZ in loopnames){
    dtmeans <- dt[, .(means=mean(ZZZ)), by=category]

    ggplot(dt) + geom_histogram(aes(x=ZZZ, fill=category)) +
                 geom_vline(data=dtmeans, aes(xintercept=means, color=category))
}
```

but obviously it doesn't work. Use of the `ZZZ` variable produces errors in `data.table` and `ggplot`.

Note the reasons behind some lines of the code:

- I want to build a list of the columns to iterate through, defined by difference: `dt` could have hundreds of columns and I only want to exclude, say, two of them.
- I need to construct a data table, containing the means, to pass to `geom_vline` (a data table for this is overkill in my opinion, but hey that's what `ggplot` wants).
- I'd like to use the special syntax of `data.table` to construct such data table.

Consulting the useful answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12603890/6090141), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12391950/6090141), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22309285/6090141), I've tried various combinations to make the code-idea above work: using `with=FALSE` for the data table, the `quote()`/`eval()` pair, the "unquote" `!!` character, as well as `as.names()` and `sym()`. But no combination worked out. Closest to solving the problem was the `quote()`/`eval()` pair, which seems to work for both `data.table` and `ggplot`, but I didn't manage to use this workaround in a for-loop.

Can you suggest a general way **without using tidyverse commands** to deal with variable/looped column names in packages such as `data.table` and `ggplot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `get(ZZZ)` in loop body, instead of `ZZZ`

Comment: and `aes_string(x=ZZZ, fill="category")`

Comment: Fantastic, `get` does the job in both packages!