# Filter data table by dynamic column name

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

lets say I have a data.table with columns A, B and C

I'd like to write a function that applies a filter (for example A>1) but "A" needs to be dynamic (the function's parameter) so if I inform A, it does A>1; If I inform B, it does B>1 and so on... (A and B always being the columns names, of course)

Example:
Lets say my data is bellow, I'd like to do "A==1" and it would return the green line, or do "B==1 & C==1" and return the blue line.

[image]

Can this be done?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variably selecting/assigning to fields in a data.table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/variably-selecting-assigning-to-fields-in-a-data-table)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your data is

```
a <- c(1:9)
b <- c(10:18)
# create a data.frame
df <- data.frame(a,b)
# or a data.table
dt <- data.table(a,b)
```

you can store your condition(s) in a variable `x`

```
x <- quote(a >= 3)
```

and filter the data.frame using `dplyr` (subsetting with [] won't work)

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, x)
```

or using `data.table` as suggested by @Frank

```
library(data.table)
dt[eval(x),]
```

Comment: thanks for the tip anyway, it works like a charm on data frames

Comment: Nice solution; there is something very similar for `data.table`, actually: `setDT(df)[eval(x),]`

Comment: @Frank Thx. Feel free to post it. If not, should I include it?

Comment: Yes, please go ahead and add it (if you want). I mentioned it here because I thought it was a natural fit with your answer.

Answer (score 15):

You can try

```
f1 <- function(dat, colName){dat[eval(as.name(colName))>1]}
setDT(df1)
f1(df1, 'A')
f1(df1, 'B')
```

If you need to make the value also dynamic

```
f2 <- function(dat, colName, value){dat[eval(as.name(colName))>value]}
f2(df1, 'A', 1)
f2(df1, 'A', 5)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(A=sample(-5:10, 20, replace=TRUE), 
      B=rnorm(20), C=LETTERS[1:20], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
dt = data.table(A=c(1,1,2,3,1), B=c(4,5,1,1,1))

f=function(dt, colName) dt[dt[[colName]]>1,]
#> f(dt, 'A')
#   A B
#1: 2 1
#2: 3 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why write a function? You can do this...

**Specifically:**

d.new=d[d$A>1,]

*where* `d` is the dataframe `d$A` is the variable and `d.new` is a new dataframe.

**More generally:**

```
data=d #data frame
variable=d$A #variable 
minValue=1 #minimum value
d.new=data[variable>minValue,] #create new data frame (d.new) filtered by min value
```

**To create a new column:**

If you don't want to actually create a new dataframe but want to create an indicator variable you can use `ifelse`. This is most similar to coloring rows as shown in your example. Code below:

`d$indicator1=ifelse(d$X1>0,1,0)`

Comment: `A` needs to be dynamic, like `myvar <- "A"` and you only work with `myvar`. With a `data.table` you could do `d[get(myvar)>1,]` or with a data.frame, `d[d[[myvar]]>1,]`, but I don't think `$` can solve this problem.