# How to use a variable in the i position to filter rows

Tags: r, data.table

Example data

```
d<-data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

I want this result:

```
d[a < 3]
```

How do achieve the same Using `my.column`?

```
my.column<-'a'
d[my.column < 3]
#Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: a
```

Although the following works, I hope there is a better way:

```
setnames(d,my.column,"my.column")
d[my.column<3,]
setnames(d,'my.column',my.column)
```

Note that this also does not work

```
setkey(d,my.column)
```

Comment: Try `d[get(my.column) < 3]`

Comment: A similar question with some additional options: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29564002/1191259

Comment: Thanks,  I didn't search on "dynamic column name."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by David in comment you can use

```
d[get(my.column) < 3]
```

The other way, which I personally prefer, is to build a call for `i` instead of getting the variable:

```
d[eval(as.name(my.column)) < 3]
```

Not sure about the performance when using in `i`. In case of using in `j` arg I believe the `eval(as.name(` would be marginally faster - depends on amount of columns AFAIK.