# Passing variables to do assignments inside function

Tags: r, function, data.table

I have several data tables with the same variable that requires intensive data tidying. I thought on creating a function but I am struggling to pass the variable name, which is shown in both sides of the `:=` assignments.

See a MWE with `mtcars` where the variable to alter is `wt`. I have tried `substitute` and `eval` but to no avail.

How would I make the code below work? What is missing? Why this one does not work?

```
DTmtcars <- data.table(mtcars)

wt_correction <- function(.df = NULL, .wt_var = NULL){
  .df[cyl==4, .wt_var := .wt_var*2]
  .df[cyl==6, .wt_var := .wt_var*3]
  .df[cyl==8, .wt_var := .wt_var*0.5]
  return(.df)
}

wt_correction(.df = DTmtcars, .wt_var= "wt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a compilation of various SO answers, the following seems to be working for me:

```
wt_correction <- function(.df = NULL, .wt_var = NULL){
  .df[cyl==4, (.wt_var) := get(.wt_var)*2]
  .df[cyl==6, (.wt_var) := get(.wt_var)*3]
  .df[cyl==8, (.wt_var) := get(.wt_var)*0.5]
  return(.df)
}
```

[Source 1 (Matt Dowle's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/select-assign-to-data-table-when-variable-names-are-stored-in-a-character-vect)

[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562602/access-data-table-columns-with-strings)