# How to order columns of the data frame according to the string variables taken from the column

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to order the columns of the data frame according to the text variables given in the column of another data frame (using `srtcolorder` from the `data.table`). Let's say, that i have first data frame (`df1)` with columns named and ordered as "five", "two" "three", "one", "four", and have another data frame with the column (`df2$names`), containing the string variables ordered as "one", "two", "three", "four", "five". How can I order the columns of the df1, according to the variables in `df2$names`?

I have tried to use `setcolorder` as follows:

```
gf3<-setcolorder(df1, key=df2$names)
```

And get an error message

> Error in setcolorder(df1, key = df2$names) : 
>   unused argument (key = df2$names)

Comment: If it's a data.table do `df1[, mget(df2$names)]` . Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562602/access-data-table-columns-with-strings

Comment: Please make your question more reproducible by adding current and expected output. Provide sample data with `dput(head(df,n))`.

Comment: argument name is `neworder` not `key`....

Comment: Dear Sindri Baldur,
Thank you for your reply. I have tried df3<-setcolorder(df1, neworder=as.character(df2$names)) and R has returned with an error message "Names in neworder not found in x", although there are the names in x, the same as in df2$names.

Comment: Dear NelsonGon,
thank very much for your reply. I am not sure that dput(head(df,n)) could work here, because my data set consists of 2087 observations of 183 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no data was provided, I created dummy data frames to simulate the data you are trying to rearrange.

The first data frame, `df1`, contains the character columns `five`, `two`, `three`, `one`, and `four` in that order:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  five = character(),
  two = character(),
  three = character(),
  one = character(),
  four = character()
)
```

The second data frame, `df2`, contains a single column titled `names` with the column names in `df1` sorted by their numerical equivalents.

`df2 <- data.frame(names = c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'))`

Data frames can be sorted with either an ordered vector containing the column indices or the column names. In this case, we can call `df1[, as.character(df2$names)]` to sort `df1`'s columns. `as.character()` is used to convert the factor vector of `df1` column names into a string vector.

If you are keen on using `data.table::setcolorder()`, you can call `setcolorder(df1, as.character(df2$names))` instead. A benefit of this method is that you do not have to assign the resulting data frame to the variable `df1`. Your attempt did not work because (1) there is no `key` parameter for the `setcolorder()` function (there is only `neworder`)  and (2) your `df2$names` was likely a factor vector (you can check by calling `class(df2$names)`).

Comment: Dear Benjamin, 
thank you for your reply. Actually, the class of variables in df2$names is already set as a character vector. However, I have used as.character(df2$names), but the R has returned an error message "Names in neworder not found in x", although there are the names in x, the same as in df2$names.

Answer (score 0):

I thank you all for your replies. I understood my mistake. There where occasionally some spaces before the strings in the df2$names, which could not be seen on the screen. Therefore, text in this column did not match the column names in df1. I have remembered a similar problem which I had with the "invisible" spaces and just intuitively tried `gsub(" ", "" df2$names)` to remove them. Thereafter, `df3<-setcolorder(df1, neworder=key(as.character(df2[["names"]]))` worked perfectly.
Thank you all again.

Comment: Fyi, there is also a function trimws() to drop leading and trailing spaces.