# Use string as column name in data.table constructor

Tags: r, data.table

Say I want to create a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) with a column whose name is specified in a string. I can do it like so:

```r
# Load library  
library(data.table)

# Name for my column
mycol <- "Column Name"

# Create data table
dt <- data.table(1:5)

# Peek
dt
#>    V1
#> 1:  1
#> 2:  2
#> 3:  3
#> 4:  4
#> 5:  5

# Rename
names(dt) <- mycol

# Peek
dt
#>    Column Name
#> 1:           1
#> 2:           2
#> 3:           3
#> 4:           4
#> 5:           5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

My question is, can I make this more concise by using the string in the constructor? Something like `dt <- data.table(eval(mycol) = 1:5)` (which doesn't work).

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12392269/1552004), which explains several ways to *add* variables whose names are strings to *existing* data tables, but this doesn't explain how to do this in data.table's constructor. Is it possible?

Comment: Not pretty and not more concise but ```eval(parse(text = paste0("data.table(`", mycol, "`=1:5)")))```. Isn't `setnames()` the way to go here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using `setnames()` like so:

```
dt <- setnames(data.table(1:5), mycol)
```

or

```
dt <- data.table(1:5)
setnames(dt, mycol) # Update by reference
```