# How can I make update by reference faster than shallow copy?

Tags: r, data.table

I created some code where I need to do a lot of joins in a loop with about 1M rows. At first I was making shallow copies with a left join, but I changed the code to make update join and it became slow.

Some test data

```
a=data.table(id=1:10^6)
b=data.table(id=1:10^6, t='y')

cols=setdiff(names(b),names(a))
c=copy(b[a,on=.(id)])
a[b,(cols):=mget(cols),on=.(id)]
all.equal(a,c)
[1]TRUE
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to compare times, but here it is

**shallow copy**

```
microbenchmark(c=b[a,on=.(id)])
Unit: milliseconds
expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
c 120.5911 122.734 128.1071 124.0922 126.1449 179.0127   100
```

**updating the data.table**

```
microbenchmark(a[b,(cols):=mget(cols),on=.(id)])
Unit: milliseconds
expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
a[b, `:=`((cols), mget(cols)), on = .(id)] 159.6128 162.9798 175.9855 168.5807 184.8756 308.5406
neval
100
```

altrough I will need a solution to update multiple columns, don't know why but, using `mget` is slower than below approach

```
microbenchmark(a[b, t:=i.t, on=.(id)])
Unit: milliseconds
expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
a[b, `:=`(t, i.t), on = .(id)] 138.0173 140.4671 146.3558 141.6204 143.281 185.1488   100
```

In this case I'm not concerned about memory usage just speed. Is there a way to update the original table without copies faster than the copy method?

Comment: Don't use mget as it may be subefficient, use env var instead

Comment: @jangorecki I will be studying about environments, but could you provide some example how to use it? I using it inside a function where the names in `cols`change based in the values provided by the user. Another doubt that I had right now with `mget` and don't know if you can help me, but if I use it inside a function and have the same object name outside the function it will always access the object created inside the function? I did some test and it's whats happened, but reading the help it's not clear.

Comment: @jangorecki, while I'm familiar with envvars (`..varname` notation for up-one-level access) and newly informed on the wip `env=list(...)` argument, I cannot get something like `dfa[dfb, c(cols) := .(..cols), on = .(id)]` to work correctly. I'm guessing it's a subtle problem I'm not seeing, but I think it would be really helpful if you could expand on your first comment. Thanks! (R.Cowboy, I renamed the vars to `dfa` and `dfb`, since I really dislike having an object named `c` in R, so I renamed all three.)

Comment: (If it matters, the expression in my previous comment functions without error but assigns a new column `t` (correct) with the literal value `"t"` (incorrect) instead of the *contents* of `dfb[,cols,with=FALSE]`.)

Comment: @r2evans the way you suggested without `mget`seems to work with a single column in `dfb` but when I create another one and try to join this way it gives an error ... don't know if I need to do some adjust

Comment: AFAICT documentation and examples covers that use case very well. Look for env=list(.rhs=as.list(cols)). Also use verbose=TRUE for debugging env argument.

Comment: @Jangoreski, do you confirm that  new `env` parameter is only in [Unreleased data.table v1.14.1 (in development)](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/news/index.html)

Comment: @jangorecki, while I am interested to play with `env=`, I am not comfortable working with a WIP package *in production* without significant testing on my own packages and code; this is not a reflection on `data.table`, just my process of reproducible processing/reports (console, `plumber`, `shiny`, and kafka-streaming) and an aversion to update any package arbitrarily. I think this use-case is relevant enough to determine ***if*** it can be done pre-`env=list(..)`; the answer may be "no". You are among few I would trust whole-heartedly to find a good method if one exists. Thanks!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60263274/should-i-use-mget-or-with-false-to-select-columns-of-a-data-table. `mget` is slow because internal code needs to allocate memory to the `.SD` variable. I will post a solution that is a less user friendly way to do `env = list(...)`.

Comment: env arg is just friendly way to use base R substitute, @Cole answer is great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a language way to approach it. Basically, [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) is awesome and does its best to optimize. However, other programmatic trickery like `mget` makes `data.table` less efficient as it has to assume that the `j` expression could include any column and therefore it needs to allocate memory to evaluate.

This translates `mget` into what is actually happening using language: `a[b, (cols) = list(t)]`.

```
nms = lapply(cols, as.name)
eval(substitute(a[b, (cols):= .x, on = .(id)], list(.x = as.call(c(quote(list), nms)))))

## performance against mget()

bench::mark(lang = {
  nms = lapply(cols, as.name)
  eval(substitute(a[b, (cols):= .x, on = .(id),], list(.x = as.call(c(quote(list), nms)))))
}
, mget_approach = a[b,(cols):=mget(cols),on=.(id)]
, normal =  b2[a2,on=.(id)]
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression        min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr
  <bch:expr>    <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int>
1 lang            157ms   160ms      5.97      23MB     1.99     3
2 mget_approach   244ms   255ms      3.92    57.3MB     5.87     2
3 normal          162ms   174ms      5.82    34.4MB     3.88     3

## additional data to make above work: a2 = copy(a); b2 = copy(b)
```

Here is the source code of where `mget` is detected and [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) needs to account for it.

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/94a12475f737892c542d3cb7daf42e534ea13a22/R/data.table.R#L1044-L1049

```
    # added 'mget' - fix for #994
    if (any(c("get", "mget") %chin% av)){
      if (verbose)
        catf("'(m)get' found in j. ansvars being set to all columns. Use .SDcols or a single j=eval(macro) instead. Both will detect the columns used which is important for efficiency.\nOld ansvars: %s \n", brackify(ansvars))
        # get('varname') is too difficult to detect which columns are used in general
        # eval(macro) column names are detected via the  if jsub[[1]]==eval switch earlier above.
```