# Specifying variables used in regression-formula using a string

Tags: r, data.table, regression

I am performing a regression using `data.table`. However, I would like to dynamically specify the right-hand side of the formula as in the following example:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(data.frame("a"=seq(1,10,1), 
                            "b"=seq(1,20,2), 
                            "c"=seq(1,30,31),
                            "d"=c("one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
                                  "two", "two", "two", "two", "two")))
varname <- "a"

dt[, lmtest::coeftest(x = lm(get(varname) ~ b),
                      vcov. = sandwich::NeweyWest(x = lm(get(varname) ~ b)) ), by = "d"]

do.regr <- function(rhs) {
  dt[, lmtest::coeftest(x = lm(get(varname) ~ rhs),
                        vcov. = sandwich::NeweyWest(x = lm(get(varname) ~ rhs)) ), by = "d"]
}

do.regr("b+c")
```

This gives an error. Is there a way to pass a string and have that being the variables used on the right-hand side of the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute on the language:

```
do.regr <- function(rhs) {
  rhs <- parse(text = rhs)[[1]]
  varname <- as.symbol(varname)
  eval(bquote(dt[, lmtest::coeftest(x = lm(.(varname) ~ .(rhs)),
                        vcov. = sandwich::NeweyWest(x = lm(.(varname) ~ .(rhs))) ), by = "d"]))
}

do.regr("b+c")
#works
```

The only disadvantage is that you couldn't use data.table's dot alias because `bquote` would (try to) substitute it. You could use `substitute` instead of `bquote` if this becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reformulate` to create formula object.

```
do.regr <- function(dt, varname, rhs){
  lmtest::coeftest(x = lm(reformulate(rhs, varname), data = dt))
}

do.regr(dt, varname, c('b', 'c'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question to generalize the situation a bit more - does `reformulate` still work?

Comment: It doesn't work as it is if you want to apply this by group. Maybe try Roland's approach or I could think of is splitting by `d` and apply reformulate on each list.

Answer (score 1):

The OP has asked to pass the right-hand side as a parameter to the `do.reg()` function but has specified the left-hand side dynamically as well in a variable `varname`.

Therefore, I suggest to pass both the left-hand side and the right-hand-side as parameters to the `do.reg()` function.

The approach below picks up [Roland's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63776773/3817004) to *compute on the language* but uses `glue::glue()` for string interpolation and a helper function `EVAL()` which I find more readable, IMHO :

```
EVAL <- function(...) eval(parse(text = paste0(...)), envir = parent.frame(2))
do.regr <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  EVAL(glue::glue("dt[, lmtest::coeftest(x = lm({lhs} ~ {rhs}),
                        vcov. = sandwich::NeweyWest(x = lm({lhs} ~ {rhs})) ), by = d]"))
}
```

The helper function `EVAL()` has been [suggested by Matt Dowle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12392269/3817004) in order to create one expression to be evaluated, "similar to constructing a dynamic SQL statement to send to a server".

The function can be called as

```
do.regr("a", "b+c")
```

or

```
do.regr(varname, "b+c")
```

and returns the same result as

```
dt[, lmtest::coeftest(x = lm(a ~ b+c),
                      vcov. = sandwich::NeweyWest(x = lm(a ~ b+c)) ), by = d]
```

> ```
>       d           V1
>  1: one 5.000000e-01
>  2: one 5.000000e-01
>  3: one 1.046778e-16
>  4: one 2.738990e-17
>  5: one 4.776564e+15
>  6: one 1.825490e+16
>  7: one 2.023596e-47
>  8: one 3.625202e-49
>  9: two 5.000000e-01
> 10: two 5.000000e-01
> 11: two 3.289712e-16
> 12: two 2.416974e-17
> 13: two 1.519890e+15
> 14: two 2.068702e+16
> 15: two 6.281080e-46
> 16: two 2.491017e-49
> ```