# Specific column selection from data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R. The table has column names.
I have a vector named colnames with a few of the column names in the table.

```
colnames<-c("cost1", "cost2", "cost3")
```

I want to select the columns whose names are in the vector colnames from the table.
The name of the table is dt.

I have tried doing the following:

```
selected_columns <- dt[,colnames]
```

But this, does not work, and I get an error.
However, when I try the following, it works:

```
selected_columns <- dt[,c("cost1", "cost2", "cost3")]
```

I want to use the vector variable (colnames) to access the columns and not the c("..") method.
How can I do so?

Comment: Could you send your dt? Because with a dt that I made, it works for me.

Comment: Does tis answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12392269/13513328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
dt[, .SD, .SDcols = colnames]
```

Meanwhile, data.table gives an alternative choice in recent version:

```
dt[, ..colnames]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another nice alternatives is leveraging [`select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html) from [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org)/[`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) universe. [`select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html) gives you a lot of flexibility when selecting columns from a data frame / tibble or data table.

```
library("data.table")
library("tidyverse")
df <- data.table(mtcars)
columns_to_select <- c("cyl", "mpg")
select(df, columns_to_select)
```

You can also skip quoting column names if you wish

```
select(df, c(cyl, mpg))
```

or leverage ellipsis and pass multiple quoted or unquoted names

*Here, comparing multiple objects.*

```
objs <- list(select(df, c(cyl, mpg)),
             select(df, cyl, mpg),
             select(df, "cyl", "mpg"))
outer(objs, objs, Vectorize(all.equal))
```

You may want to have a further look at [`dtplyr`](https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org), which provides a bridge between data table and dplyr, if you want to go this route.