# Data.table with a custom function

Tags: r, data.table, custom-function

I am new to data.table, coming from dplyr. I have the following custom function tabs:

```
tabs <- function(dt, x) {
tab2 <- dt[!is.na(x), ][, .(Freq = sum(nwgt0)), by = .(inc_cat, year, x)][, Prop := Freq / sum(Freq), by= .(inc_cat, year)][order(inc_cat, year)][x == 1 & !is.na(inc_cat), ] %>%
   ggplot(., aes(x= year, y = Prop, color = factor(inc_cat, levels = c(1,2,3,4),labels = c("0% to 100% FPL", "101-138% FPL", "139-200% FPL", ">200% FPL")))) +
    labs(color = "Income Categories") +
    geom_line() +
    theme_minimal() +
  ylab("Weighted proportion") +
   theme(
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  )
return(tab2)
}
```

I now wish to call the function tabs .

I have tried the following (does not work):

```
result <- hints_dt[ , tabs(.SD, x='internet_use')]
```

And receive the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt[!is.na(x), ], , .(Freq = sum(nwgt0)), by = .(inc_cat,  : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length(s) (22344,22344,1). Each must be length 22344; the same length as there are rows in x (after subsetting if i is provided).
```

Should be using .SDcols to specify the column internet_use. If so, how do I modify my function?

Thanks,

Felippe

EDIT: per comments below, I include a `reprex` here. Using data from NHANES `data("nhanes")` I adapted the function `tabs`:

```
tabs <- function(dt, x) {
tab2 <- dt[!is.na(x), ][, .(Freq = sum(WTMEC2YR)), by = .(race, agecat, x)][, Prop := Freq / sum(Freq), by= .(race, agecat)][order(race, agecat)][x == 1 & !is.na(race), ] %>%
   ggplot(., aes(x= year, y = Prop, color = factor(race, levels = c(1,2,3,4),labels = c("hispanic", "white", "black", "other")))) +
    labs(color = "Race") +
    geom_line() +
    theme_minimal() +
  ylab("Weighted proportion") +
   theme(
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  )
return(tab2)
}
```

When I run `result <- nhanes[ , tabs(.SD, x="RIAGENDR")]` I was able to reproduce my error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt[!is.na(get(x)), ], , .(Freq = sum(WTMEC2YR)),  : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length(s) (8591,8591,1). Each must be length 8591; the same length as there are rows in x (after subsetting if i is provided).
```

Comment: Since you are passing `x` to the function as a character string, try using `get(x)` rather than just `x`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/select-assign-to-data-table-when-variable-names-are-stored-in-a-character-vect

Comment: `by` will take a vector of columns as character strings. Try `by = c("inc_cat", "year", x)`

Comment: @jblood94, thanks, when I run your suggestion that code runs now. But I get an empty data.table object (list of lists).

Comment: It will be hard for me to track down why without the data. Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the suggestion. When I use `get(x)`, I get the following error: `Error in .checkTypos(e, names_x) : 
  Object 'internet_use' not found amongst inc_cat, year, get, Freq, Prop`

Comment: @jblood94, just added a reproducible example using dummy data from NHANES, data that is similar to my real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get(x)` works fine for the LHS/RHS of the `` data.table::`:=` `` operator,

```r
MT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
fun <- function(DT, v) DT[!(get(v) == 4),]
fun(MT, "cyl") # WORKS
```

But your use of non-standard evaluation (NSE) within `by=` will not work with this.

> ***Note***: for the sake of this argument, I'm mimicking your code by having the function have built-in `by`-grouping hard-coded. If the function can only be used with a specific dataset then this is often fine, but if you try to generalize the function, know that you should "never" assume fields in more general calls on other data.

```r
fun2 <- function(DT, v, by) DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = v, by = .(gear, by)][]
fun2(MT, v="disp", by="cyl")
# Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = v, by = .(gear,  : 
#   The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length(s) (32,1). Each must be length 32; the same length as there are rows in x (after subsetting if i is provided).
```

We *can* use `get(by)` within the NSE `by=` as well,

```r
fun2 <- function(DT, v, by) DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = v, by = .(gear, get(by))][]
fun2(MT, v="disp", by="cyl") # works
```

But this may not always be the case. I find in these situations it is often good to recall that `by=` can be either the NSE that you're using or a character vector.

```r
fun2 <- function(DT, v, by) DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = v, by = c("gear", by)][]
fun2(MT, v="disp", by="cyl") # works
```

using `by=c(..)` instead of `by=.(..)`. This can also work with inequality joins, where `data.table` internally parses and evaluates them, such as `by=c("gear", paste(v, ">", otherv))` (assuming we have another variable `otherv` for the join-comparison).

From here, whatever else you do in the rest of the function should attempt to do the same thing: use `v` as a character vector.

Note that I have setup this function so that `v` can be length-1 or more.

Comment: thanks for the helpful comment! It worked!